# How does one stop VS code from going into normal mode in Vim when doing normal copy `Cmd + c`?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

whenever I select code and then do `Cmd + c` (copy) it then goes by itself to normal mode in vim. So:

1. How do I stop VS code from doing that?
2. Why is it doing that?

---

My default keybinding for copy paste has (go to command pellet type keybinding go to default keybindings):

```
{ "key": "cmd+c",                 "command": "execCopy" },
```

---

probably this: `{ "key": "cmd+c",                 "command": "extension.vim_cmd+c",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.overrideCopy && vim.use<D-c> && !inDebugRepl" },` except it doesn't let me edit the file!?!?!

Comment: what vscode VIM extension are you using?

Comment: @CharlieParker this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim vscode vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without seeing your exact extension configuration and system info, it's hard to say with certainty, but you may have an extension conflicting with or overriding the default behavior.

open the command palette and type `keybindings` and choose the command to edit keybindings.    you can search for `cmd+c` to see if anything else is using it, and in what context. alternatively, you can do this directly from your `keybindings.json` file.

also, for the sake of diagnostic, you can always launch vs code with no extensions enabled just to see if it is indeed an extension problem.  if so, you can selectively enable extensions, and when you find the right one, you can look within its internal settings

Comment: this is my copy paste keybinding `{ "key": "cmd+c",                 "command": "execCopy" }`

Comment: I want vim but without it whenever I copy sending me to normal mode

Comment: vscode reads the key binding file top to bottom (or vice versa?) so if vim inserted its own ctrl+c after, it could be taking precedence... just speculation, but I had to change the order with an extension TabOut which changes the functionality of tab key

Comment: probably this: `{ "key": "cmd+c",                 "command": "extension.vim_cmd+c",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.overrideCopy && vim.use<D-c> && !inDebugRepl" },` except it doesn't let me edit the file!?!?!

Comment: That's almost certainly it. I think there might be already a question on SO about being unable to edit keybindings.json, but if not, that would be a worthy question in itself. I actually remember having that specific problem, but I don't remember the exact solution, it might have been that there was a syntax error and it was very fussy about that. can you not simply copy the whole contents, delete the file, paste into a new file renamed keybindings.json?  you might also check your problems pane to see if the file is throwing any warnings

Comment: I wrote in my answer how to overcome the uneditable file. For some reason vs code is picky about this file and wants you to go to their own window to edit the file if you want to change it. Command pellete and then select keyboard shortcuts (not the json file!)

Comment: what VIM extension are you guys talking about/using?

Comment: @CharlieParker this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim vscode vim

Answer (score 13):

I feel the answers are longer than need.

Follow these steps:

1. Command palette `Cmd+shift+P`
2. Type `Open Keyboard Shortcuts` (not the Json one)
3. Nice looking file in vscode comes up like pinocchio said (see attached image)
4. Search `cmd+c`
5. Go the the row that has in it's column `extension.vim_cmd+c`
6. Click it and then hit backspace (or right click select remove).

Done.

---

For sake of context see Snippet:

[image]

Comment: This should be the correct answer. :+1
Look like you finally nailed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this answer is less "hacky" than the other answers, and therefore less likely to cause unexpected side-effects.

In the "User Settings", disable the "Vim: Override Copy" setting.

[image: Screenshot of the Override Copy setting]

Alternatively, in the "User Settings (JSON)", add the following line:

```
"vim.overrideCopy": false,
```

These settings are accessible by pressing Cmd+shift+P, then selecting "Preferences: Open User Settings" or "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As Tedskovsky suggested, go to the json file that has the keybinding. Find the last one that maps `cmd+c` to something. Then remove it. Though, that file can only be opened in read mode so you will need open:

```
Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts `Cmd+K Cmd+S`
```

**NOT THE JSON ONE** (at least not in vscode):

[image]

So the first one (not the second one).

That opens a nice looking window that allows you to edit the keyboard settings. Probably the last one in that list I assume. I went to the uneditable one and found the last one and removed it (and yes as Tedskovsky suggested, it was added by the vim extension).

The name of it was:

```
{ "key": "cmd+c", "command": "extension.vim_cmd+c", "when": "editorTextFocus && vim.active && vim.overrideCopy && vim.use<D-c> && !inDebugRepl" },
```

search is somewhere in your default editable file to remove it (click and select remove).

Don't select the json file for the keyboard bindings if you want to change it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I've found that if you put in the effort, vs code can be extremely efficient and customizable, but it does require some sleuthing...

Comment: @Tedskovsky Thanks so much Tedskovsky! :D Yes I love vs code. But the pain so far has been worth it. I've been most productive I've ever been in my entire life! :) This one was a big one cuz I didnt have this issue in atom.

Comment: No problem.  Out of curiosity, did you try editing `keybings.json` with the editor closed?  I wonder if it's locked when VSC is open to prevent users from accidentally nuking themselves -- since while editing, the whole file is inherently invalid -- and then does a sanity check on open.

Comment: @Tedskovsky I did not try that (I also assumed the same thing you said so it made sense it didn't let me but I was to lazy to find its path to edit somewhere else). I ended up just googling how to edit the file anyways and thats when I found the other option in the command pellet. Also, I implicitly trusted vs code through their interface to avoid unexpected issues. Thats the last thing I need right now! :-D

Comment: what VIM extension are you guys talking about/using?

Comment: @CharlieParker this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim vscode vim

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings.json and add this:

```
"vim.handleKeys":{
  "<C-c>": false
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).